# Distinct Kissing number configurations

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, spheres

How many essentially distinct kissing number configurations are there for the dimensions 3 & 4?  (I know the answer for dim 1,2,8,24).

Comment: What's an essentially distinct kissing number configuration?

Comment: Dimensions 1,2,8,24 have a unique configuration - it's up to equivalence. For instance, although the center n-sphere might be touching k(n) other spheres, the other spheres may or may not touch k(n) spheres in the set of spheres touched by the center sphere.  For instance, in the case n=2, k(n)=6, and there is a unique configuration - as drawn in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KissingNumber.html

Comment: The problem is (for example) that in three dimensions, there's wiggle room.  You put them at the corners of an icosahedron—that's the basic configuration—but they can all move a little.  I think the question joriki might be asking is: How far could they move before you would consider it an essentially different configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christine Bachoc and Frank Vallentin, in "[New Upper Bounds For Kissing Numbers From Semidefinite Programming](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2008-21-03/S0894-0347-07-00589-9/S0894-0347-07-00589-9.pdf)" (2007), indicate that

> For dimension $3$, there are infinitely many possible configurations.  In the regular icosahedron configuration, the angular distances between the contact points are strictly greater than the required $\pi/3$; hence these points can be moved around obtaining infinitely many new suitable configurations.  This partially explains why the determination of $\tau_3$
>   is difficult. On the contrary, uniqueness of the optimal configuration of points in dimension $4$ is widely believed, but it remains unproven.

This latter configuration refers to the lattice $D_4$, which yields the four-dimensional kissing number of $24$ (finally proven in 2003 by Oleg Musin, using a clever modification of the linear programming method devised by Philippe Delsarte and others).  I haven't found any reference that indicates that this uniqueness has been established in the last decade or so.