# Best non-lattice configurations for the Kissing number problem

Tags: geometry, spheres

I am studying the [Kissing Number problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number). We know the optimal kissing number for dimensions 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 and 24. For all of these, the optimal configurations stem from highly symmetrical lattices. The best known arrangements for dimensions 5, 6 and 7 also stem from lattices.

I am wondering, what are the best known **non-lattice** configurations for each dimension?

Comment: In dimension 3 at least it is possible to get the same center density and kissing number with a non-lattice construction. The idea is described in Conway & Sloane. You get the lattice by repeating a chosen 2D-layer with constant displacement from one layer to the next. But you get the same amount of kissing by using non-constant displacement (hence non-lattice).

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen! Do you know if the same can be done in higher dimensions? I suppose one could always start with a lattice and then shift some of the spheres by a small amount. Although not sure if there is any room to do that in the $E_8$ lattice?

Comment: By the way, are you interested in configurations around a single sphere, or do you still want a pattern that can continue in the entire space?

Comment: I just want a configuration around a single central sphere.

Comment: My guess is that $E_8$ and Leech are so unique that there is no wiggle room, but I may be wrong about this.

Comment: Ok, the WP page you linked to already discusses how there is a lot of extra room in 3D to move the 12 kissing spheres around.

Comment: Actually, given how difficult the optimality proofs are, I am not betting in favor of uniqueness around a single sphere. I don't remember/know what kind of uniqueness results have been discovered.

Comment: The solution uniqueness is discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463443/distinct-kissing-number-configurations